# How to register a new zip file extension on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I have a file extension (.pbiviz) that I would like Windows 10 to treat as a standard '.zip' file.  I tried 'open with' and manually tried 'c:\windows\explorer.exe' but this showed an error message.

Is there any configuration in windows 10 registry where the list of valid zip file extensions is registered?

[Edit] More details to ensure this is clear.

I have files with the extension `pbiviz` that are zip files.  Now I do not want to rename the file 'zip' every time I look into those files and then have to rename back.

So I'm looking for a way for windows 10 explorer to automatically detect and treat these files as zip files.

With 3rd party applications this is easy as you can just register them with 'Open With' as the default application.  However, you cannot do that with Windows Explorer as it does not show on the 'Open With' list.

Comment: Um, you open it with the application you _really_ want to use.

Comment: I take it from the tone that perhaps my question was not clear.  I have expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and install the following .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pbiviz]
@="CompressedFolder"
"Content Type"="application/x-zip-compressed"
"DontCompressInPackage"=""
"PerceivedType"="compressed"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pbiviz\OpenWithProgids]
"CompressedFolder"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pbiviz\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

Comment: works perfectly